# why objc_retain has two parameters in IDA disassembled pseudo code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reverse-engineering, ida

Since I'm a newbie to reverse engineering, I can't understand why, in `v8 = objc_retain(a3, a2);` sentence, the `objc_retain()` function has two parameters and even a return value! As far as I know, the function `objc_retain` in runtime library just gets one parameter and no return value. how does this `objc_retain` work with its two parameters?

```
char __cdecl -[NSString writeToAppFile:tag:userInfo:error:](NSString *self, SEL a2, id a3, id a4, id a5, id *a6)
{
  NSString *v6; // r10
  id v7; // r5
  int v8; // r8
  int v9; // r1
  int v10; // r11
  int v11; // r1
  int v12; // r6
  void *v13; // r0
  void *v14; // r4

  v6 = self;
  v7 = a4;
  v8 = objc_retain(a3, a2);
  v10 = objc_retain(v7, v9);
  v12 = objc_retain(a5, v11);
  v13 = objc_msgSend(v6, "dataUsingEncoding:", 4);
  v14 = (void *)objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue(v13);
  LOBYTE(v7) = (unsigned int)objc_msgSend(v14, "writeToAppFile:tag:userInfo:error:", v8, v10, v12, a6);
  objc_release(v12);
  objc_release(v10);
  objc_release(v8);
  objc_release(v14);
  return (char)v7;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Expecially, that it has two different signatures `(id,SEL)` and `(int,int)`. Maybe objc_release is a kind-of preprocessor macro in your case? Can you jump to / show us the definition of that function?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen This code snippet is not the source code, but the IDA disassembled pseudo code. So I cannot get the definition of this function. Thank you, Andreas.

Comment: I guess it is just something the disassembler cannot determine, due to some weired Objective C / ARC secrets. See also: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-01-06-the-hopper-disassembler.html (near the end)

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I'm sorry to tell you that I just cannot open the link you drop me and I don't know why. I tried to use `curl` to access the link and got this error message `curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.mikeash.com:443`

Comment: I also do not know why. Just use a web search engine and search for "mikeash The Hopper Disassembler", and you'll find the web site.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Ok, I'll figure it out. Thanks again.